# How to approximate a fraction of gamma functions evaluated at huge values

Tags: real-analysis, asymptotics, gamma-function, approximation-theory

For sufficiently large $m$, one can approximate the function

$$f:m\mapsto\frac{\Gamma \left(\frac{m+1}{2}\right)^2}{\Gamma \left(\frac{m}{2}\right) \Gamma \left(\frac{m}{2}+1\right)}$$

using the taylor polynomial with some degree $n$ of $f(z=1/m)$ in the limit $z\to 0^+$,  i.e.

$$1-\frac{1}{2 m}+\frac{5}{8 m^2}-\frac{11}{16 m^3}+\frac{83}{128 m^4}-\frac{143}{256 m^5}+\frac{625}{1024 m^6}-\frac{1843}{2048
   m^7}+\frac{24323}{32768 m^8}+\ldots$$

However, the radius of convergence at $z\to 0^+$ is $0$, so if $m$ is fixed this approximation doesn't converge (although being very close when using an appropriate degree).

If $m$ is huge and fixed, is there any alternative which will converges to arbitrary precision if sufficiently many iterations/terms/something else are used?

Comment: I think that the expansion would be $$1-\frac{1}{2 m}+\frac{1}{8 m^2}+\frac{1}{16 m^3}-\frac{5}{128 m^4}-\frac{23}{256
   m^5}+\frac{53}{1024 m^6}+O\left(\frac{1}{m^7}\right)$$

Comment: You can use $\Gamma(x+1) = \sqrt {2 \pi} e^{-x}x^{x+1/2}$

Comment: You could use a [convergent version of Stirling's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation#A_convergent_version_of_Stirling's_formula).